# import json file to mongodb atlas collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am a beginner I would like to import a json file to mongodb atlas collection. so I found these [instruction](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/) on how to import using mongodbimport , i followed all the instruction with no success. i am stuck at step 5 running mongoimport. when I run it on mongodb shell i got an error `undefined token` if I exit mongo shell and run it on windows command I got this error `mongoimport is not defined`

bellow is the command iam trying to run

```
mongoimport --host cluster0-shard-00-02-cr0y2.mongodb.net:27017 --db default_default --type json --file <FILEPATH> --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD>
```

I also tried the uri option

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb://root:<PASSWORD>@atcluster0-shard-00-02-cr0y2.mongodb.net:27017:27017/default_default?ssl=true&replicaSet=myAtlasRS&authSource=admin" --collection Business --drop --file <FILEPATH>
```

after spending many hours trying  i am completely confused on what command I should run and where to run it ?

thank you for your help

Comment: You've got a few things going on at once.   So it seems you can run the shell, yes?   OK.   Wherever that shell resides (i.e. the path to mongo.exe) you should also find mongoimport.exe.   Let's start by making sure you start mongoimport.exe and then we will move onto command line params.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti thank you for your feedback . I searched I dont think I have a mongoimport.exe file . i directly created an account with mongodb atlas and I connected to it via nodejs. so nothing was intalled to my computer . do I need to install mongodb on my computer in order to execute mongo import ? or is it possible to run the shell command directly from the nodejs ?

Comment: Atlas is where DB lives; `mongoimport` is a command line utility.   Yes, you have to install the mongo "package" on your computer to install the `mongoimport` util.   It will also install (but not run) the actual `mongod` DB engine but you won't be using that with Atlas.   Here is good link to follow: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/